# How to overload function by argument object shape in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, function, overloading

Suppose I want to check the string's length, in **2 ways** (fixed or range):

```
/* Fixed check */
check('abc', {length: 1}); // false
check('abc', {length: 3}); // true

/* Range check */
check('xyz', {minLength: 5, maxLength: 10}); // false
check('xyz', {minLength: 1, maxLength: 10}); // true
check('xyz', {minLength: 3, maxLength: 3}); // true
```

I first declared the 2 interfaces as follows:

```
interface StringFixed {
  length: number;
}

interface StringRange {
  minLength: number;
  maxLength: number;
}
```

Then I try to write the function:

```
function check(value: string, schema: StringFixed): boolean;
function check(value: string, schema: StringRange): boolean;
function check(value: string, schema: StringFixed | StringRange): boolean {
  if (typeof schema.length !== 'undefined') { // ERROR
    // Fixed check
  } else {
    // Range check
  }
}
```

But now the TypeScript reports the ERROR in the first line of the function:

```
TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'StringFix | StringRange'
```

My question is how to do this in TypeScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **so** close. :-) You're asking for the type of the value of a property that you expect to be there (`typeof schema.length`). To implement a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), you want to ask **if** the property is there:

```
if ("length" in schema) {
    // Fixed check
} else {
    // Range check
}
```

[Working copy on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5gMWADwgBNkBvAKGWQBsIQswALALmRAFcBbAI2gG5yAX3LlQkWIhTpM9AEpx6KClU6gAMnQYs2XXlAEq4+DfSasOPfkJEx2IBGGAB7EMgSMICANYAKAG5w1OwQrADOGNgANMih7hCccKzS2HiERACUrNxOTrQKArb2ji5uHt7+gcFhEfTRsR4JSTVY8oqZyNm5EPnkhQ7OrnHlAUEhMc11cY1ozanEyAA+MzItClgQ7Z15rsrIwDDIPgBEtKaMR3uu9fFw6WSUVMgA9E-IcyRDXg9UUBBg7FBXCNggA6U5aZAAXmhMSmcDBmiYBmQgmQEGooSU32er1a61Kni+j2Qv3+gOQwIgCLOyAAfJDYQ14aoQCYIQAydkUypU8FMZAAHgZ1wSIISxkRjGRwkEQA).

Comment: thank you! I really should read the official docs more closely. Btw, can't wait to read your new book ~